# Drupal redirect to homepage after login

Tags: php, authentication, drupal

**context** : I have a drupal website that is only accessible to logged in users.

#### Expected behavior

I send this link to my client : `mywebsite/path/to/mypage`

My client click on the link, it redirects him to the loggin page and then redirect to `mywebsite/path/to/mypage`

#### Current behavior

I send this link to my client : `mywebsite/path/to/mypage`
My client click on it, he get redirected to the loggin page and then gets redirected to the homepage `mywebsite`

#### Research

My guess is that it's coming from `.htaccess` but I haven't touched it.
I tried a fresh new install of both drupal and apache and got the exact same behavior

Comment: You did not even mention which Drupal version, let alone which extensions are in use.

Comment: @CBroe Drupal version : `9.5.2`. Extension in use : `User module`

Answer (score 0):

This module allows you to choose a redirect path after login: https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect_after_login

OR

you can define a query parameters ?destination in your url.
Drupal use it to redirect to the page of your choice, example:
mywebsite/path/to/mypage?destination=/path/to/mypage

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that doesn't really solve the problem. I don't want to redirect people based on their role, I want them to follow the link I sent them. Also, the second solution might work for me, but I don't expect client1 to know how to modify a url just send a link to client2.

Comment: For the second solution you only need to add ?destination= to the link that you give it.